# SQL*Loader-605: Non-data dependent ORACLE error occurred

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sql-loader

As I try to load data into Oracle, I've encountered `SQL*Loader-605: Non-data dependent ORACLE error occurred` error.

Data is (are?) in `.txt` file and its size is 95GB.

Here are some more details about the error:

> value used for ROWS parameter changed from 64 to 19
>
> ORA-01653: unable to extend table M.ECZ by 8192 in tablespace USERS
>
> SQL*Loader-605: Non-data dependent ORACLE error occurred -- load discontinued.
>
> Specify SKIP=8351926 when continuing the load.
>
> Table ECZ:
>     8351925 Rows successfully loaded.
>     0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
>     0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
>     0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.
>
> Space allocated for bind array:                 245100 bytes(19 rows)
>   Read   buffer bytes: 1048576
>
> Total logical records skipped:          1
>
> Total logical records rejected:         0
>
> Total logical records discarded:        0

What do you advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've simply run out of space in the DB you are loading the data into. Try:

```
SQL> select file_name, bytes/1024/1024/1024 as gb from dba_data_files where tablespace_name='USERS';
```

Let's say the file was `/data/users01.dbf', 32G in size. Then you might do

```
SQL> alter tablespace users add datafile '/data/users02.dbf' size 1g autoextend on next 1g maxsize unlimited;
```

That will give you up to another 32G of space. Repeat as necessary, 03, 04 etc. I don't know how much Oracle data your 95G text file will end up as, but you can see what is available with:

```
SQL> select tablespace_name, sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 as Gb from dba_free_space where tablespace_name='USERS' group by tablespace_name;
```

Comment: Also see `select * from dba_tablespace_usage_metrics;` :-)